# How to get only odd numbers from a slider?

Tags: c++, slider

I have a slider control from a GUI that gives values from 1 to 400, I need to assign only odd numbers from the slider to a variable, but I dont know how to get just the odd numbers from it, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: There is no *slider* in C++. You will have to provide more context.

Comment: @IInspectable The standard C++ slider!

Comment: It's a slider control from a GUI library I'm using

Comment: There is no GUI in C++. Please provide context. Qt? Windows API? MFC? Some other framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the slider has an interface that lets you check its value you can do something like this:

```
Slider* slider = However you get your slider;
int sliderValue;

// Use modulus division to determine if slider value is odd
if(slider->getValue() % 2 == 1) {
    sliderValue = slider->getValue();
}
```

Comment: My god it was that easy! must that a break now THANKS

Comment: @Ricardo This produces a mismatch between UI representation and internal state. A proper UI would represent the actual value. You should consider modifying the slider control to force it being set to odd values only.

Comment: @IInspectable That is a very good point. I myself am pretty new to UI programming, so I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming like Todd that the slider has an interface that lets you check its value I would take the value and reduce it by 1 iff it's even:

```
Slider* slider = However you get your slider;
int sliderValue = slider->getValue();
sliderValue -= (1 - sliderValue % 2);
```